# drawing images on 3 layer canvas and saving

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a 3 layers of canvas, which I have given a separate id to each.

This is what I am doing.

**HTML**

```
<div style="position:relative;">
    <canvas id="layer1" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 0;">
    </canvas>
    <canvas id="layer2" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 1;">
    </canvas>
    <canvas id="layer3" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 1;">
    </canvas>
</div>
```

I can draw images on layer1

**JS**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('layer1');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.canvas.width  = window.innerWidth;
context.canvas.height = window.innerHeight*0.7;
var imageObj = new Image();
var imageObj1 = new Image();

imageObj.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0,context.canvas.width,context.canvas.height*0.9);
    context.drawImage(imageObj1, x1, y1,6,canvasHeight);    
};

imageObj1.src='vertical.png';
imageObj.src = 'horizontal.png';
```

How will I draw images on all the layers and create single canvas.toDataUrl ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I save div as image at client side where div contains one or more than one HTML5 canvas elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880330/how-can-i-save-div-as-image-at-client-side-where-div-contains-one-or-more-than-o)

Comment: but i am unable to display images on layer 2 and layer 3

Comment: You would do that just like with `layer1`.  You need another context based on `layer2`, etc.  `var canvas2 = document.getElementById('layer2');  var context2 = canvas.getContext('2d');`

Answer (score 6):

To draw on all three “layers” you must create contexts for all layers

```
// references to layer1
var canvas1 = document.getElementById('layer1');
var context1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');

// references to layer2
var canvas2 = document.getElementById('layer2');
var context2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');

// references to layer3
var canvas3 = document.getElementById('layer3');
var context3 = canvas3.getContext('2d');
```

Then after you’re done drawing on all layers, merge them (here merged onto layer1):

```
// merge all layers onto layer1
context1.drawImage(canvas2,0,0);
context1.drawImage(canvas3,0,0);
```

And finally save the merged canvas to an image and set your img src to that image.

```
// save the merged drawings as an image
// and set the img element src to that merged image
var img=new Image();
img.onload=function(){
    document.getElementById("results").src=img.src;
}
img.src=canvas1.toDataURL();
```

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/fhjwY/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

// references to layer1
var canvas1 = document.getElementById('layer1');
var context1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');

// references to layer2
var canvas2 = document.getElementById('layer2');
var context2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');

// references to layer3
var canvas3 = document.getElementById('layer3');
var context3 = canvas3.getContext('2d');

// draw stuff on the layers
context1.fillStyle="red";
context2.fillStyle="blue";
context3.fillStyle="green";

context1.fillRect(20,20,50,50);
context2.fillRect(50,50,50,50);
context3.fillRect(80,80,50,50);

// merge all layers onto layer1
context1.drawImage(canvas2,0,0);
context1.drawImage(canvas3,0,0);

// save the merged drawings as an image
// and set the img element src to that merged image
var img=new Image();
img.onload=function(){
    document.getElementById("results").src=img.src;
}
img.src=canvas1.toDataURL();



}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <p>Draw rects on 3 canvases</p>
    <p>Merge all drawings to 1st canvas</p>
    <p>Create an image from merged drawings</p>
    <p>Set the image element with that merged image</p>
    <canvas id="layer1" width=150 height=150></canvas>
    <canvas id="layer2" width=150 height=150></canvas><br>
    <canvas id="layer3" width=150 height=150></canvas>
    <img id="results" width=150 height=150>
</body>
</html>
```