# displaying a combined canvas image in a pop-up window

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm using the results on a previous Stackoverflow page to combine various layers on an html canvas:  [drawing images on 3 layer canvas and saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17554168/drawing-images-on-3-layer-canvas-and-saving)

And the resultant jsfiddle seems to be what I am after.
But now what I'm hoping to do is display that final composited image in a pop-up window (sized to the dimensions of the image) which will appear when the user clicks a button, but I am unsure how to do this.

I have thought about using the `window.open()` command but this seems to only open a pre-created webpage.

PS I am looking for a **javascript** solution not **jQuery**, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pass the img src to the new window

```
window.open(img.src,"image window",`width=${img.width},height=${img.height}`);
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fhjwY/84/